# Download manager that can cope with disconnects (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, download-manager

I have a dodgy internet connection that frequently disconnects. The disconnections are usually only for a short period of time, say about 10-30 seconds.

When the disconnection happens, Chrome and Firefox downloads fail, and they do not automatically try and continue where they left off after the internet connection is back up again, although they are capable of continuing downloads where they left off, but this requires manual intervention; not handy for overnight downloads.

Please share your knowledge if you know of such a download manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**uGet**](http://ugetdm.com/) is a lightweight and very powerful download manager application. You can install uGet in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with this command:

```
sudo apt install uget
```

There is an option in the uGet settings to always show a uGet system tray icon in the notification area of the panel to the left of the clock and volume icons.

#### Features

- Resume downloads  – If your connection is interrupted, you can start right back where you left off with download resuming. (not guaranteed, it's server controlled and cannot be bypassed by a download manager)
- Queue downloads
- Classify downloads in categories
- Batch downloads
- Multi-Protocol – support for downloading files through HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, BitTorrent and Metalink
- Clipboard monitoring
- Import a list of URLs to download via .txt or .html files

uGet also can be launched from the terminal with the command: `uget-gtk`

Comment: This is great, i've been using uGet for a couple of hours now and it handles the connection resets perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The download manager **XDM** (or Xtreme Download Manager) should do be a great option.

[**XDM Hompage**](http://xdman.sourceforge.net/#downloads)

From the Features list:

> Download Resume.
>   XDM will resume unfinished download from the place where they left off. Comprehensive error recovery and resume capability will restart broken or interrupted downloads due to lost or dropped connections, network problems, computer shutdowns, or unexpected power outages.

And here is an all detailed guide on [How To Install Xtreme Download Manager On Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-xtreme-download-manager-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Comment: I have just tried this software, and it was absolutely terrible; buggy as hell.